# if else true condition to check in PHP

Tags: php, json, if-statement

i want a simple simply check if the json file contains **latest**  in the beganing than it should do some function, if the json file contains **videos** in the beganing than it should do some other functions.
This is my PHP code ---

```
$url = 'http://www.hello.se/3209406a5d0f95&limit=15';
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);

if($json['latest']['videos']){ // how can i just put a condition where if it is true than 
//do some function or if it is not true go to the next condition which is else if($json['videos']){ ...

        // do some functions
       }
else if($json['videos']){
// do some functions
```

i have also tried like so ----

```
$url = 'http://www.hello.se/3209406a5d0f95&limit=15';
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);

if($json['latest']['videos'] === true){

        // do some functions
       }
else if($json['videos'] === true){
// do some functions
```

which is not working for me, can anyone help me to fix this issue.
Any advice will be really appreciate, thanks in advanced.

Comment: can you show how the json file looks like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `isset()` : http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

```
if(isset($json['latest']['videos'])){ // how can i just put a condition where if it is true than 
//do some function or if it is not true go to the next condition which is else if($json['videos']){ ...

        // do some functions
       }
else if(isset($json['videos'])){
// do some functions
```

Comment: you're welcome, :) mark it as resolved if it's the case